# How to process/select/iterate based on random percentage value in the Spring Batch Processor?

Tags: java, loops, iteration, spring-batch

This is Spring Batch application, where reader passes 1 object at a time to the processor. However there can be many(thousands of) objects being read/processed.

In the processor, only select values randomly based on the passed in percentage - which is an integer value (less than 100).

This percentage value is configurable and sent as job param to the Batch application.
It can be any 10%, 20%, 25% 30%, 50%, 75%, etc so on.

Say for example if its 50%, then only 1 out of 2 object received by processor would be processed & the other would be ignored(return null).
If it's 75%, then 3 out of 4 objects received by processor would be processed & 1 would be ignored.

i was thinking of something like this

```
    int current = 0;

public <T> process(<T> item) {

    JobParameters parameters = stepExecution.getJobParameters();
    int randomPercent = parameters.getString("percentage");
    // randomPercent = 50;

    int num = 100/randomPercent;  
    // num = 100/50 = 2

    if(current % n == 0) {
       // process this object
       current++;
       return item;

    } else {
        // do not process this
        current++;
        return null;
    }
}
```

the above code doesn't work in case where *randomPercent* is greater than 50%.

is there any better/elegant way to handle the percentage value and iterate based on it.

Thanks!

Comment: I have 2 questions.
Do you have a minimum numbers of object?
What does the writer do?

Comment: 1. at a minimum there might be a few hundred item/objects
2. based on the randomPercent value, 
if the item is processed by processor it is sent to writer , writer sends notification, if item is not processed, processor returns null to writer - nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your input, I'm thinking a way as below.

The processor will have a queue to process. If the queue is filled up to 100, we will start pick up items by percentage and send the list to Writer. Otherwise, processor will keep filling items to the queue.

The code as:

```
@Value("#{jobParameters['percentage']}")
private Integer percentage;

private List queue = new ArrayList();
private Integer count = 0;

public List<<T>> process(<T> item) {
        count ++;

        if (count == 100) {
            List result = pickupItemByPercentage();
            this.count = 0;     // reset
            this.queue.clear(); // reset;

            return result;
        }
        else {
            this.queue.add(item);
            return null;
        }
}

/**
 This method is to return a list of item base on the percentage
**/
private List pickupItemByPercentage() {
    List result = new ArrayList();

    // TODO: you can change the logic to pick up items if you want.
    for (int i=0; i<this.percentage; i++) {
        result.add(this.queue.get(i));
    }

    return result;
}
```